# Creating first zend 2 project

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm new to zend framework

After setting up all requirement settings(composer and wamp), I ran the following command

```
composer create-project --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application ./pizza
```

I get the following error

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
"https://packages.zendframework.com/packages.json" does not contain valid JSON
Parse error on line 1:
ة{    "packages": {
^
Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

What could cause like these error?

Comment: In front of your JSON data there is some weird symbol. But don't see it in this link.

Comment: As above, there is what looks like an arabic char. As this data is comming directly from zend, and i dont see the char my edit, my guess is that you are connecting through some kind of proxy that is adding it

Comment: Have you runned a composer self-update before?

Comment: This weird symbol is an Arabic letter, I don't know where it come from, This error happened before and after running composer self-update

Answer (score 0):

1. `git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git YourAppName`
2. `php composer.phar update`

or

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```